# Character Array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to build a char array of words using calloc.

What I have:

```
char** word;
word=(char**)calloc(12,sizeof(char*));
for(i=0;i<12;i++){
word[i]=(char*)calloc(50,sizeof(char));
}
```

Is this correct if I want a char array that has 12 fields each capable of storing 50 characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. Some points:

- No need to cast return value of `calloc()` ( [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) )
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1

So code could be rewritten as:

```
char** word;
int i;

word = calloc(12, sizeof(char*));
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    word[i] = calloc(50, 1);
```

In C, most of the functions that operate on 'strings' require the `char` array to be null terminated (`printf("%s\n", word[i]);` for example). If it is required that the buffers holds 50 characters and be used as 'strings' then allocate an additional character for the null terminator:

```
word[i] = calloc(51, 1);
```

As commented by [eq-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463074/eq) a less error prone approach to using `sizeof` is:

```
word = calloc(12, sizeof(*word));
```

Comment: + Using `sizeof *ptr_variable` lessens the probability of erring with `sizeof`.